# how check method and return his result(if he exist) without create variable with result method?

Tags: php

```
public function ForTest(){
   $test = $this->CheckTest();
    if(!empty($test)){
       return $test;
    }
    return 'go next';
}
```

Can i check result method and return result(only if he exist) without create `$test`?

P.S.: if `$this->CheckTest` retun `0`, `false`, or other empty result method  `ForTest()` should return `do next`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not expecting results of `CheckTest()` method to be `0`, `''` or any other falsy values to be valid you can do it like this:

```
...
{
    return $this->CheckTest() ?: $this->doNext();
}
...

function doNext()
{
    return 'some other value';
}
```

Comment: Or did I misunderstood you and you need to continue the execution if there is no value returned from `CheckTest`?

In that case I think you will have to create a variable.

Comment: if method `$this->CheckTest();` return `'',false or 0` hi not should return `null` and use `return`,  becose in this clause method where `CheckTest()` is call will be stoped.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but I've edited my answer too.
Maybe you should clarify why do you need this in the first place and maybe we will help you find a better solution.

Comment: under `go next` i mean code which working after method `$this->CheckTest();` i.e. if `$this->CheckTest();` return not empty result, that it result show, else execute code after `$this->CheckTest();`. i can check as i write in question, but i whould like know can be make check with alternative method(way), that not create variable `$test`

Comment: You can create another method that will do the stuff you need in case `CheckTest()` returned empty value.